# I am writing a mobile number tracking code and when I run my code I am getting KeyError: 'long' Error code

Tags: python, geolocation, phone-number

### That's the full error code;

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19272\1604950283.py in <module>
     48 
     49 lat = results[0]["geometry"]["lat"]
---> 50 long = results[0]["geometry"]["long"]
     51 
     52 print("Phone Number Cordinates Location:",lat, long)

KeyError: 'long'
```

### that's the code section

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)
query = str(location)
results = geocoder.geocode(query)
print(results)


lat = results[0]["geometry"]["lat"]
long = results[0]["geometry"]["long"]

print("Phone Number Cordinates Location:",lat, long)

my_Loc = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start = 9)
folium.Marker([lat, long,], popup = location).add_to(my_Loc)


my_Loc.save("my_Location.html")
```

Comment: What is the output of the `print(results)`?

Comment: It's likely that "long" is not a key in the `results[0]["geometry"]` map. Printing the data in `results` as @HMH1013 suggests should list out all the available keys. I wouldn't be surprised to find out it was "lon" or something like that just to match the length of "lat".

Comment: The key is 'lng' not 'long'

Comment: @DarkKnight, It worked thank you, surprisingly I am getting the coordinates but not of a phone number,

Comment: @HMH1013 i am getting this :     [{'annotations': {'DMS': {'lat': "14° 31' 8.08356'' S", 'lng': "27° 33' 32.35824'' E"}, 'MGRS': '35LND6022894809', 'Maidenhead': 'KH35sl75bl', 'Mercator': {'x': 3067852.555, 'y': -1623112.321}, 'OSM': {'edit_url': 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?relation=195271#map=17/-14.51891/27.55899', 'note_url': 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/note/new#map=17/-14.51891/27.55899&layers=N', 'url': 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/?..........................plus more of coordinates

Comment: @Emil It's possible I may be missing something, but upon reading the documentation (https://opencagedata.com/api) it doesn't seem like OpenCage is meant to provide a phone number or any kind of mobile identifier as part of its results and mainly provides geographical information. The documentation for the Python port doesn't seem to mention this either (https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder).

I'm not sure about the structure of your project, but you may need to build the correlation between phone number and location some other way.